# Intellij Structural search functional interfaces

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, structural-search

I've finally changed the java version of my android project to 8.
Now, I want to use structural search to find all existing functional interfaces and replace them with lambdas.

I've reached till the point where I can find the Anonymous classes :

```
new $AnonymousClass$() {
    @Override
    public void $MethodName$() {
        $Expr$;
    }
}
```

But, the problem is it'll list those anonymous classes also which are not functional interfaces and therfore can't be converted to lambdas.

How do I refine my query to find only the functional interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the built-in inspections
`Java | Java language level migration aids | Java 8 | Anonymous type can be replaced with lambda` and `Java | Java language level migration aids | Java 8 | Anonymous type has shorter lambda alternative`? Those also have quick fixes to do the replacing for you.

Comment: This inspection just highlights them. But can I apply quick fix in bulk to all of them? AFAIK, I have to go apply it individually on each item.

Comment: Yes, you can. Invoke `Analyze | Run inspection by name...`, choose the inspection you want and run on your entire project. IntelliJ IDEA will present the result in a tree where you can invoke quick fix on the whole project or any part of the result tree you want.